# Making Value Reactive with GetX in Widget Setup

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm new to GetX and am trying to migrate a project from Provider. I am using [multi_split_view](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_split_view) in my app to have resizable panes, and I set it up in a `StatefulWidget` like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<PilotProApp> {
  final MultiSplitViewController _splitViewController = MultiSplitViewController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var menu = Provider.of<ModelMenu>(context); //<-- Old provider variable
    final menu = Get.put(ControllerMenu()).menu; //<-- New GetX observable

    //Update splitView areas for Dashboard
    _splitViewController.areas = menu.value == 'Dashboard'
        ? [Area(weight: .75), Area(weight: .25)]
        : [Area(weight: .25), Area(weight: .75)];

    MultiSplitView splitView = MultiSplitView(
      controller: _splitViewController,
      children: const [
        Master(),
        Detail(),
      ],
    );

    MultiSplitViewTheme splitViewTheme = MultiSplitViewTheme(
      data: MultiSplitViewThemeData(dividerThickness: 16),
      child: splitView,
    );
  }
}
```

I know that I have to wrap a widget in `Obx(()=>)` in order to make it reactive, but the place I need reactivity here is where it says `//Update splitView areas for Dashboard`. In Provider, when the `menu` variable changed, it would reset the `_splitViewController.areas`.

But with GetX, I'm unclear on how to make a configuration change like that reactive. Where should `Obx(()=>)` go in this case? Or do I need to move my entire `MultiSplitViewController` into my `ControllerMenu` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Well that didn't take long to figure out. Let me know if I'm wrong on this, but I think I can make my widget a `StatelessWidget` and put my `MultiSplitViewController` in my controller like this:

```
class ControllerMenu extends GetxController {
  final menu = 'Dashboard'.obs;
  final splitViewController = MultiSplitViewController();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    //Watch for changes on `menu`
    ever(
      menu,
      (value) {
        //Update controller
        if (value == 'Dashboard') {
          splitViewController.areas = [Area(weight: .75), Area(weight: .25)];
        } else {
          splitViewController.areas = [Area(weight: .25), Area(weight: .75)];
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then I just plug in my `MultiSplitViewController` back into my view:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final splitViewController = Get.put(ControllerMenu()).splitViewController;

  MultiSplitView splitView = MultiSplitView(
    controller: splitViewController,
    children: const [
      Master(),
      Detail(),
    ],
  );
}
```

Seems to work great!